# Getting an error trying to install Windows Migration Service to Server 2019

Tags: migration, system-administration, windows-server-2019

I am doing a migration from an old server to a brand new server. I am trying to install the Windows Migration Service and keep getting the following error
[The Referenced Assembly Could Not Be Found. Error: 0x80073701](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9f2SM.png)

Looking at the logs it creates when trying to install I see: this a bunch of times:
Failed to pin deployment while resolving Update: Package_1791_for_KB4523205~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.10.4523205-2657_neutral from file: (null) [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]
2020-09-03 11:01:23, Info                  CBS    Failed to bulk stage deployment manifest and pin deployment for package:Package_3722_for_KB4565349~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~10.0.1.5 [HRESULT = 0x80073701 - ERROR_SXS_ASSEMBLY_MISSING]

I tried to install those updates (KB4565349, KB4523205), but it said they were already installed or not applicable. I have not tried to uninstall the updates then reinstall yet.

I am not sure why I cannot install the service and am leaning towards just trying to get the new server re-imaged.